# How to check checkbox on clicking an image?

Tags: android

I have created a gridview and added a checkbox in it.On clicking on checkbox grid view item which are image view with textview get selected.

But I want to check the checkbox on tap of grid view item.

This my MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            GridView gridview;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



                gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.mainGrid);

                gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this));

                gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                            long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //
        //



                        ImageAdapter.holder.ItemCheck.setId(position);
                        ImageAdapter.holder.ItemCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                //ImageAdapter.holder.ItemCheck.setChecked(true);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Itemclicked" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                        Toast.makeText(
                                MainActivity.this, "Itemclicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                };


            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

        }
```

This is my AdapterClass

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        private Context mContext;
        public static ViewHolder holder;



        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //ViewHolder holder;
            View myView = convertView;
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                //Inflate the layout

                 holder = new ViewHolder();
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(8, 8,8, 8);




                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);           
                myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_items_ontap, null);

                 holder.ItemCheck = (CheckBox) myView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                    myView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) myView.getTag();
            }
    //      holder.ItemCheck.setId(position);
    //      holder.ItemCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    //
    //          public void onClick(View v) {
    //              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //              Toast.makeText(mContext, "Itemclicked" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //          }
    //      });


                // Add The Image!!!           
                ImageView iv = (ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image_OnTap);
                iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


                // Add The Text!!!
                TextView tv = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text_onTap);
                tv.setText(names[position] );


                holder.ItemCheck.setChecked(isEmpty());
                holder.id = position;



            return myView;
        }





            public class ViewHolder {

                public CheckBox ItemCheck;
                int id;
            }



        private String[] names={"ab","cd","ef","gh","ij","kl","mn","","","","","","",""};

        private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car, R.drawable.car,
                R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.car
        };

    }
```

Gridview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

griditems.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/GridItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image_OnTap"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_text_onTap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
        android:checked="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:focusable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please suggest me.I m new to android and I got stuck here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check the checkbox on tap of grid view item.

you can do it by using second parameter of `onItemClick` method as:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    CheckedTextView check = (CheckedTextView) view;
    check.setChecked(!check.isChecked());
    boolean click = !check.isChecked();
    check.setChecked(click);
    if (click) {
        //write what you want whenever click a checkbox
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks....its working..But if i want to uncheck it on click of grid item then what should i do...

Comment: if you want to unchecked CheckBox then use `if (itemcheck.isChecked()) {itemcheck.setChecked(true);}else{itemcheck.setChecked(false);}`

Comment: A shorter way would be `itemcheck.setChecked(!itemcheck.isChecked())` :)